# Workspace Switcher doesn't work from the launcher

Tags: 11.10, workspaces

I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and everything seems to be running smoothly except for one thing: I can't seem to get the Workspace Switcher to work.

When I press the launcher icon, my desktop flickers and fades into black, but doesn't do anything else until I press the icon again and everything comes back. Any idea what might be going on? It was working fine in 11.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out -- under Expo in CCSM, I had the animation set to 'Fade and Zoom'. Switching it to just 'Zoom' did the trick.